# Prolog - List Member with K

Tags: prolog

```
 listMem(L, K, LK): LK is the list L with element K inserted in it somewhere.
```

I am having trouble writing this function, but my attempt goes as so: 
My idea was to add K to L, then sort it and check if that sorted was the same as LK, unfortunately it doesn't work so well. I am having doubts of my use of the append predicate.

```
 listMem(L, K, LK) :- append(L, K, Y), sort(Y, LK).
```

Comment: try `?- L=[1,2,3],K=a,select(K,LK,L).`, could inspire you

Comment: i hope i was inspired as intended, i came up with this: listMem(L, K, LK) : - select(K, LK, X), sort(X, Z), sort(L,Z) ?

Comment: I would drop both sort calls

Comment: but i need to check if L is contained in LK, just the select wouldnt do it.

Comment: @TeodoricoLevoff have you read the manual regarding what `select/3` does? Why do you say, *just the `select` wouldn't do it*?

Comment: @lurker To be fair, the manual does not usually explicitly state the different "modes" for predicates; a basic understanding of Prolog however is enough to know how to read and understand the manual (usually).

Comment: @Boris yes, you're right. The manual is often terse reference. The OP could, though, explain better why they say it doesn't work for them. It might help elucidate a misunderstanding they're having regarding predicates.

Comment: I haven't looked into select prior to this question, but now that I look at it I don't get how to call select vs select\3 , because select/3(E, [a,b,c],L). gives me an error.

Comment: One might naively assume that before diving into writing Prolog you might have at least some basic understanding of naming and calling conventions for the language. Otherwise it's like trying to write a C program without being told that you need an `int main()` or semicolons after statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it seems you are missing the difference between a function and a Prolog predicate:

```
?- select(E, [a,b,c], L).
E = a,
L = [b, c] ;
E = b,
L = [a, c] ;
E = c,
L = [a, b] ;
false.

?- select(x, L, [a,b,c]).
L = [x, a, b, c] ;
L = [a, x, b, c] ;
L = [a, b, x, c] ;
L = [a, b, c, x] ;
false.

?- select(x, [a,b,c], L).
false.
```

In a sense, "select" as a word means less than what `select/3` does, but, as CapelliC pointed out, what you are looking for is indeed `select/3`. You can see how it is implemented in any Prolog textbook or [check out the library implementation of an open-source Prolog implementation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/home/swipl/lib/swipl/library/lists.pl?show=src#select/3).